# Execution from the statement select * into return error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can somebody help me?

I am try execute the command below in Oracle 11 and I get this error:

> SQL Error [905] [42000]: ORA-00905: keyword not found.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
INTO SAJ.ETMP_TESTE 
FROM SAJ.ESAJOBJETO O 
WHERE CDOBJETO = 'P800000000J03'
```

I read the Oracle docs and haven't found any obvious error in my statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm

My objective is to create the table `ETMP_TESTE` with structure from `ESAJOBJETO`.

I checked user permission and user has permission to action.

Comment: Have you tried listing all the columns instead of `*`?

Comment: I change to below and has error yet.
SELECT CDOBJETO, CDTIPOOBJETO, TPPRIORIDADE, NUFLUXOPARALELO, DELISTATARJA, CDCONFIGAVISOFLU INTO SAJ.ETMP_TESTE 
FROM SAJ.ESAJOBJETO O 
WHERE CDOBJETO = 'P800000000J03'

Comment: `SELECT ... INTO` is PL/SQL syntax, not SQL; the documentation you liked to is the PL/SQL user guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  create table and not select into  for create a table based  on the result of a query

```
CREATE TABLE SAJ.ETMP_TESTE 
AS   SELECT *  
FROM SAJ.ESAJOBJETO O 
WHERE CDOBJETO = 'P800000000J03'
```

Comment: The statement is good, but whether i have 

`with Objeto as (select * from MyTable) CREATE TABLE ETMP_295752_61_ESAJOBJETO AS SELECT * FROM Objeto`

Result error: SQL Error [928] [42000]: ORA-00928: SELECT KEYWORD not found

Comment: with Objeto as (select * from MyTable) CREATE TABLE is not a valid sintax  .. and is not mentioned in your question  .. what do you mean  ??  .. you have posted  only a part of the code???

Comment: @Willimar - you can use a CTE but you have it in the wrong place: `CREATE TABLE ETMP_295752_61_ESAJOBJETO AS with Objeto as (select * from MyTable) SELECT * FROM Objeto` would work (but doesn't add anything in that example).

Answer (score 2):

This will create an empty table named ETMP_TESTE, with the structure of the SAJ.EASJOBJETO table.

```
CREATE TABLE ETMP_TESTE AS
SELECT *
FROM SAJ.EASJOBJETO
WHERE 1 = 0;
```

This does not handle contraints and primary keys and things like that, but it will get you the table structure.  The 1 = 0 makes sure no data is copied.

If you need primary keys and the like, look into extracting the [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) for EASJOBJETO.  Most SQL IDEs have that functionality built in.  You can edit it to correct the table name and run the script and get everything.